# How to reference NaN values in pandas dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am just iterating through a simple pandas dataframe that looks like something like this:

```
   229041189 229041196 229041197 229041200 229041211 229041212 229041216  
0        C-T       T-C       C-T       C-T       G-T       G-T       C-T  
1        C-T       T-C       C-T       C-T       NaN       NaN       C-T  
2        C-T       NaN       C-T       C-T       NaN       NaN       C-T  
3        C-T       T-C       C-T       C-T       NaN       NaN       C-T
```

And within an if loop i am trying to look at only those values that are not NaN but they still all pass my condition and I'm not sure why this is.

My loop is something like this:

```
for i in column:
    if i != 'NaN':
        # do something
```

Comment: Use `if pd.notnull(i)`, I think it is dupe, so only comment.

Comment: btw, why need loop? In pandas is best avoid it, because slow. What do you need?

Comment: I'm just counting incidences of each type of item but ignoring the NaN. Looping was just the best way I knew how to do that.

Comment: Hmmm, so need output from sample `7,5,4,5` ?

Comment: As an aside, to test for `NaN` directly, use `np.isnan(test_value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for check `NaN` (missing value) is possible use [`pandas.notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html):

```
if pd.notnull(i)
```

I think you need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for create `Series` by reshape - `NaN`s are dropped:

```
print (df.stack())
0  229041189    C-T
   229041196    T-C
   229041197    C-T
   229041200    C-T
   229041211    G-T
   229041212    G-T
   229041216    C-T
1  229041189    C-T
   229041196    T-C
   229041197    C-T
   229041200    C-T
   229041216    C-T
2  229041189    C-T
   229041197    C-T
   229041200    C-T
   229041216    C-T
3  229041189    C-T
   229041196    T-C
   229041197    C-T
   229041200    C-T
   229041216    C-T
dtype: object
```

And then [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
a = df.stack().value_counts().rename_axis('val').reset_index(name='count')
print (a)
   val  count
0  C-T     16
1  T-C      3
2  G-T      2
```